# Terminate docker compose when test container finishes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, concourse

I am currently running a docker-compose stack for basic integration tests with a protractor test runner, a nodejs server serving a web page and a wildfly server serving a java backend.

The stack is run from a dind(docker in docker) container in my build server(concourse ci).

But it appears that the containers does not terminate on finishing the protractor tests.

*So since the containers for wildfly, and nodejs are still running the build task never finishes...*

**How can I make the compose end in success or failure when the tests are finished?**

```
# Test runner
test-runner:
  image: "${RUNNER_IMG}"
  privileged: true
  links:
    - client
    - server
  volumes:
  - /Users/me/frontend_test/client-devops:/protractor/project
  - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
  entrypoint:
    - /entrypoint.sh
    - --baseUrl=http://client:9000/dist/
    - /protractor/conf-dev.js
    - --suite=remember
# Client deployment
client:
  image: "${CLIENT_IMG}"
  links:
    - server
# Server deployment
server:
  image: "${SERVER_IMG}"
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Compose has added the `--exit-code-from {container}` flag to [`docker-compose up`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) which makes this easier.

```
docker-compose up --exit-code-from test-runner
```

See [Michael Spector's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49485880/1318694) for more detail.

---

### Original Answer

Similar to this [rspec q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37450174/1318694), you need to run the tests as a standalone task that report an exit status back to your CI.

You could separate the test-runner into it's own yaml or modify the test-runner to default to a no op command/entrypoint.

### Separate the test runner

Specify the `test-runner` config separately (You might need to upgrade to [version 2 `networks`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/networks) instead of using `links` to work across multiple compose files).

```
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose -f test-runner.yml run test-runner
rc=$?
docker-compose down
exit $rc
```

### No op test runner

Default the `test-runner` to a no op entrypoint/command and then manually run the test command

```
services:
  test-runner:
    image: "${RUNNER_IMG}"
    command: 'true'
```

Then

```
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose run test-runner /launch-tests.sh
rc=$?
docker-compose down
exit $rc
```

#### Return codes

If your CI has the concept of "post tasks" you might be able to skip the `rc` capturing and just run the `docker-compose down` after the test-runner CI task has completed. It's also possible your CI cleans up the containers for you.

Comment: Is it possible to write something like --exit-code-from test-runner into the docker-compose file?

Comment: @SerhiiKushchenko There's nothing like `exit-code-from` in the [spec](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/)

Answer (score 152):

You can use these docker-compose parameters to achieve that:

`--abort-on-container-exit` Stops all containers if any container was
                               stopped.

`--exit-code-from` Return the exit code of the selected service
                               container.

For example, having this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    ...
  service-api:
    ...
  service-test:
    ...
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
      - service-api
```

The following command ensures that `elasticsearch` and `service-api` go down after `service-test` is finished, and returns the exit code from the `service-test` container:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up \
    --abort-on-container-exit \
    --exit-code-from service-test
```

Comment: Thanks you so much I read half of the internet to find your solution :-)

Comment: agreed, that was surprisingly hard to search for

Comment: Indeed. Starred and upvoted to make sure it's not lost again.

Comment: very ... trivial answer. I hope this answer grows to the top so everyone doesn't lose it while searching.

Comment: best answer i ever got for any question on stackoverflow !!

Comment: Nice answer! btw, you can omit `--abort-on-container-exit` 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

Answer (score 27):

The solution I found to be most elegant is to use `depends_on` in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
services:
  dynamodb:
  ...
  test_runner:
    ...
    depends_on:
      - dynamodb
```

Now you can use `docker-compose run --rm test_runner` which will set up your dependencies, run your tests, tear down everything, and propagate the return code.

```
docker-compose run test_runner false
Starting test_dynamodb_1 ... done
echo $?
1
docker-compose run test_runner true
Starting test_dynamodb_1 ... done
echo $?
```

Comment: Not sure why this isn't upvoted more - it seems to me that it solves the question much better than the accepted answer.

Comment: Note that this does not tear down dependencies, as opposed to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49485880/51197

Answer (score 3):

I have tried the solution offered in this discussion but problem still in the case

**Case-1: docker-compose up -d**

You can use `docker-compose up -d`, test it by a `test-runner` then terminate by `docker-compose down` but the problem when you use `docker-compose up -d` is that ***you won't see the logs*** of the standard output anymore.

**Case-2: docker-compose up --exit-code-from a service**

You can [*view the docker logs*](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/) if you use `--exit-code-from <service>` that implies `--abort-on-container-exit` but the service won't send exit command when it is succeeded. Then ***you need to catch*** your container is finish tested before sending `docker-compose down` to stop them.

> One of the solution [to see the logs](https://kostasbariotis.com/dont-just-docker-compose-up/) before terminating them is using `--tail=1000 -f`

```
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose logs --tail=1000 -f test-runner
docker-compose down
exit $rc
```

There is also a solution using `nohup` but you need to wait until process is completely finished then open the output logs file, so the above should be easier

Answer (score 0):

My `docker compose up` had some combination of flags (`--build`) that prevented all the service containers from being stopped when `--abort-on-container-exit` triggered.

e.g. the following:

```bash
docker compose up \
  --build service1 \
  --attach service1 --attach service2 \
  --abort-on-container-exit
```

will start both `service1` and `service2`, but will only stop `service1` when it aborts because as far as Docker is concerned it was only responsible for building `service1` and it refuses to assume that `service2` isn't pre-existing — even though it's, y'know, defined in the same docker-compose.yml and linked with `depends_on` and *it literally just started it.* It just leaves `service2` running.<sup>1</sup>

To fix this all I needed to do was make sure to run `docker compose down` after `docker compose up`.

This can be done using a `trap` to ensure that it always runs even if `docker compose up` fails and would exit the script early:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

cleanup() {
  docker compose down
}
trap cleanup EXIT  # will always run when the script exits

docker compose up \
  --build service1 \
  --attach service1 --attach service2 \
  --abort-on-container-exit
```

---

**Footnotes**

1: This was a problem for me because my `service1` expected its `service2` to be in a fresh state.

Answer (score -1):

**To avoid having separate config files** you can update the docker-compose configuration to introduce the dependencies between services with the [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on) option, available from version 2 format and up. As result start of the `test-runner` will initiate the run of the clients.

Please note that if you need to wait some time when the actual web server will be started from inside services you are testing, you can use [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) script to wait until the server became available.

```
# Test runner
test-runner:
  image: "${RUNNER_IMG}"
  privileged: true
  links:
    - client
    - server
  volumes:
  - /Users/me/frontend_test/client-devops:/protractor/project
  - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
  depends_on:
    - client
  entrypoint:
    - wait-for-it.sh
    - client
    - -t
    - '180'
    - --
    - /entrypoint.sh
    - --baseUrl=http://client:9000/dist/
    - /protractor/conf-dev.js
    - --suite=remember
# Client deployment
client:
  image: "${CLIENT_IMG}"
  depends_on:
    - server
  links:
    - server
# Server deployment
server:
  image: "${SERVER_IMG}"
```

After updating config, simple `docker-compose up test-runner` will trigger start of the related services.

Answer (score -2):

You can do clean-up tasks using `ensure` on a task step in Concourse. https://concourse-ci.org/ensure-step.html

In your case, you could add an `ensure` block after your protractor tests, and run a task to tear-down what was `docker-compose`'d earlier. You could also use an `on-success` step https://concourse-ci.org/on-success-step.html to do the teardown, and the `docker-compose`'d containers would be kept if your tests fail.