# Best Docker Stack equivalent for docker-compose "--exit-code-from" option?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I have a docker-compose file with 4 services. Services 1,2,3 are job executors. Service 4 is the job scheduler. After the scheduler has finished running all its jobs on executors, it returns 0 and terminates. However the executor services still need to be shut down. With standard docker-compose this is easy. Just use the "--exit-code-from" option:
[Terminate docker compose when test container finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907954/terminate-docker-compose-when-test-container-finishes)

However when a version 3.0+ compose file is deployed via Docker Stack, I see no equivalent way to wait for 1 service to complete and then terminate all remaining services. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack/

A few possible approaches are discussed here -
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30942
The solution from miltoncs seems reasonable at first:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30942#issuecomment-540699206
The concept suggested is querying every second with `docker stack ps` to get service status. Then removing all services with `docker stack rm` when done. I'm not sure how all the constant `stack ps` traffic would scale with thousands of jobs running in a cluster. Potentially bogging down the ingress network?

Does anyone have experience / success with this or similar solutions?